# Service starts from services.msc but not with net start

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-server-2008, services

When I launch a cmd file with "net start ..." I see "service could not be started". In logs I see that the server actually was started without any errors and then stopped. It looks like "net start" stops service if it can't be started within some timeout.

Everything works fine when I start the same service from services.msc

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround. "sc start" works fine.